# Is passing a string back to the calling code necessary in FFI modules to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: ruby, rust

I have

*lib.rs*

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn test() -> *const c_char {
    CString::from("Hello").unwrap().into_raw()
}
```

In Ruby, I call it as

*main.rb*

```rb
require 'ffi'

module Rust
   extend FFI::Library

   # [redacted loading the library]

   attach_function :test, [], :string
end

some_string = Rust::test()
```

Do I have to pass the string back to Rust to be freed? Won't garbage collection pick this `some_string` up and free it?

I'm using [*The Rust FFI Omnibus*](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/) as a reference. I ran `valgrind ruby main.rb` and it didn't seem to find any leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to pass the string back to Rust to be freed?

Yes.

> Won't garbage collection pick this `some_string` up and free it?

Yes, but that's not the memory leak to worry about. The garbage collector *will* free the memory allocated by Ruby that contains the transformed Ruby string.

However, the garbage collector has no knowledge of the *allocation* that Rust made. Specifically, the Rust code might *not* even have made an allocation. In that case, if the calling code freed the string, that would cause memory unsafety, so the FFI library cannot assume that this `char *` was an allocation.

Even if it did, it wouldn't know which allocator to use to deallocate with. Remember that there are frequently multiple allocators in play in a moderately complex application.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the *Omnibus*.